# Inserting Image using Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert an image that is stored on my google drive that I want to insert into my google sheet, using google script

Bearing in mind that i have a a whole load of images stored in my drive that i don't really want to publish to the web, but do want an automated way of doing it.

I know this question was asked about 2/3 years ago and google didn't have a method of doing it, there were workarounds like export links which have now been detracted.

insertimage() comes to mind but it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is the code I am using to get PDF and Tiff in, it is basically the code by Tainik

```
function insertDrawing(folderID, file_name) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).searchFiles('title contains "' + file_name + '"').next();
if (!~file.getMimeType().indexOf("pdf") || !~file.getMimeType().indexOf("tiff") || file == 'undefined') {
    ss.toast('No image found');
    return
} 
var res = (JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file.getId() + "?fields=thumbnailLink", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
}).getContentText()).thumbnailLink);
var r = res.split("=");
Logger.log(res)
var url = res.replace(r[r.length - 1], "s5000");
Logger.log([res, url])
return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
}).getBlob()
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether I understand what you want to do. But in the case of ``if (!~file.getMimeType().indexOf("pdf") || !~file.getMimeType().indexOf("tiff") || file == 'undefined') {``, ``ss.toast()`` in ``if`` is run for all files included pdf and tiff. When you want to use only pdf and tiff, please modify from ``if (!~file.getMimeType().indexOf("pdf") || !~file.getMimeType().indexOf("tiff") || file == 'undefined') {`` to ``if (!~file.getMimeType().indexOf("pdf") && !~file.getMimeType().indexOf("tiff") || file == 'undefined') {``.

Comment: And when PDF is used, please set the query parameter to less than ``s1100``. When ``s`` is large, an error occurs.

Comment: When you want to add and modify your question, please update your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry my mistake I was adding it as an answer. I think the syntax is correct there I only want it to put the image in if the file is either a PDF or TIFF and if it isn't to come up with file not found. May i ask where you are getting these resolution limits from. I cannot seem to find documentation that even mentions what "s5000" "s1200" means

Comment: The resolution using query ``s`` is different between mimeType. I have reported about it at https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#doresize_principle Please check it.

Comment: @Tanaike, my only issue with the answer is that the JPEg part isn't working for me anyway. I have tried a different google account same issue.

For completeness I will accept this answer as it is better than anything I had before. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample? In this sample, an image is inserted to the active sheet using the filename of image file. You can see the detail information of `insertImage()` at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(Blob,Integer,Integer).

#### Sample script 1

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertImage(
  DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename).next().getBlob(),
  1,
  1
);
```

#### Sample script 2

If you want to insert all files in own Google Drive, you can use following script. But if image files are in large number, errors may occur.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
var ar = [];
var i = 1;
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (~file.getMimeType().indexOf("image")) {
    ss.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getBlob(), i++, 1);
  }
}
```

#### Sample script 3

`insertImage()` can use the mimyTypes of png, bmp, gif and jpeg. I think that this is corresponding to [`getAs()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String)). Images with the mimeType except for them cannot be used directly. So such images have to convert the mimeTypes. But since Google Apps Script doesn't have the prepared converter for it, outer API has to be used for this situation before. Recently, I noticed that `thumbnailLink` of Drive API can be used for this situation by changing the query parameter. You can see the detail information [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#doresize).

About the sample script, I used this. This script inserts images in the specific folder. You can use the mimeTypes of png, bmp, gif and jpeg and also other mimeTypes. Although I thought high efficiency by separating "png, bmp, gif and jpeg" and images except for them, when the number of files is large, errors may occur.

```
var folderId = "### folder ID ###";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
var ar = [];
var i = 1;
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == "image/png" || file.getMimeType() == "image/bmp" || file.getMimeType() == "image/gif" || file.getMimeType() == "image/jpeg" || file.getMimeType() == "image/jpg") {
    ss.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getBlob(), i++, 1);
  } else if (~file.getMimeType().indexOf("image")) {
    var res = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file.getId() + "?fields=thumbnailLink", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }).getContentText()).thumbnailLink;
    var r = res.split("=");
    var url = res.replace(r[r.length - 1], "s5000");
    ss.insertImage(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    }).getBlob(), i++, 1);
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: What you are describing is exactly what i tired. I get the following error:

`We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 9, file "okay"`

Comment: Can I ask you about the number of files on your drive? If there are large number of files, errors may occur. When you have large number of files, it imports image files separately to folders. And then you can search files for each folder. In that case, the error can be avoided.

Comment: I created a brand new folder with 1 image file (.tiff) in there and it still gives me the same error. Modified your code like this:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id').getFiles();
var ar = [];
var i = 1;
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (~file.getMimeType().indexOf("image")) {
    Logger.log(file)
    ss.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getBlob(), i++, 1);
  }
}`

Comment: @mfizz I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. I added new sample script as Sample script 3. Please confirm it.

Comment: You know what that seems to have worked better than anything so far, so thanks. So it is only working good for TIFF

The first part of your code `if (file.getMimeType() == "image/png" || ` still doesn't work for images jpg jpeg png etc in drive. So i removed that part tried inserting using the URL fetch method it did insert however after much tinkering (s250 instead of s5000) however the resolution is really poor. for the JPEG image i tried.

Tiff on the other hand seems to be working better don't know why

Comment: @mfizz 1. PNG files can be used for this script. 2. The resolution of image is the same to the source image resolution. s5000 means one of resolution. If you have higher resolution images, you can modify it. In the case of Google Docs and PDF, the maximum resolution is 1024 in the width. But it was found that this is not the method you want. I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful.

Comment: No no, it is working for PDF and Tiff perfectly. (It just so happens that that is the 2 formats that I am working with currently) For fullness of solution, I would like to be able to import jpg and png. 

I tried to be clever and use the urlfetch method for jpegs and still got the same error

But the insertimage() doesn't seem to work (same message of .. we are sorry server error occurred please try again later). Have you tried it on yourself does it work for pictures that you have on your drive that are not public?

Comment: @mfizz Using my original script, I confirmed that png, jpeg and tiff can be inserted again and PDF cannot be inserted. Did you modify my original script? If it's so, can you show us your current one? If you can show us your current script, please put it by modifying your question. By seeing your current script, the problem may be found.

Comment: @Tainik could it be because i am using G suite apps?