# Push selected values to specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My html form has a few fields, however, I only want id, Confirmation, Questions, and Notes to be posted to their respective columns on my sheet:

[image]

How can I achieve it? I was only able to post "all" form fields to their columns based on same header name as my form name="" value.

I only want id, Confirmation, Questions and Notes to map to their right columns.

My Code.gs:

```
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)
  
  try {
    
    var sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(function(e){return e.replace(/^0/, "")}).join("/");
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) throw new Error("Sheet Name was not found.");
    
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })
    
    var find = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(newRow[0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext(); 
    sheet.getRange(find ? find.getRow() : nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
    
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow })+ ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
  
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e })+ ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT)
  }
  
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the HTML form is submitted, you want to put only the values of `id, Confirmation, Questions, and Notes` to the Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})
```

#### To:

```
var keys = ["id", "confirmation", "questions", "notes"];
var newRow = headers.map(function (header) { return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : keys.includes(header.toLowerCase()) ? e.parameter[header] : "" });
```

- In this modification, using `keys`, the values of specific keys are retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Hi Tanaike. I have one issue from your suggested code. It replaces the value of the other columns with null like the Payment Method, LA Customer, Cleaners, etc.

In this case, please modify your script in your question as follows.

#### From:

```js
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

var find = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(newRow[0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext(); 
sheet.getRange(find ? find.getRow() : nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
```

#### To:

```js
var keys = ["id", "confirmation", "questions", "notes"];
var newRow = headers.map(function (header) { return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : ~keys.indexOf(header.toLowerCase()) ? e.parameter[header] : "" });

var find = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(newRow[0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
if (find) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(find.getRow(), 1, 1, newRow.length);
  var rowValue = range.getValues()[0].map(function(c, i) {return newRow[i] || c});
  range.setValues([rowValue]);
} else {
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike. It throws an error on my browser console about Cors Policy and this: Error! Failed to fetch

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `It throws an error on my browser console about Cors Policy and this: Error! Failed to fetch`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: You're doing good. Thanks. Here's the sheet: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15RdfeerRjc-1noF2MDpA1Ce2h1VXbLOHq-akDUNDL8Q/

That above has a few columns. From my HTML form, I only wanted to post the id, Confirmation, Questions & Notes while reserving the contents of the other columns.

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your current script, it seems that the same function names are existing in a Google Apps Script project. For example, there are 2 `doPost` funcions. In this case, the script might not work. I'm worry about this. And also, your current script doesn't reflect my proposed modification. By this, I cannot replicate your current issue. I apologize for this. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and the current script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. I'm sorry I was working on it lately. I am now using your suggested code and removed the other doPost. It still doesn't work. :( My HTML form hangs up when I click the submit button. And my browser console throws this error: https://prnt.sc/15nyyk1

Comment: @geeksified Now, I noticed that your script editor disables V8 runtime. In this case, please modify `var newRow = headers.map(function (header) { return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : keys.includes(header.toLowerCase()) ? e.parameter[header] : "" });` to `var newRow = headers.map(function (header) { return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : ~keys.indexOf(header.toLowerCase()) ? e.parameter[header] : "" });` and test it again. Because `includes` cannot be used without v8 runtime. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097823) and [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57505424)

Comment: Awesome! Finally it's working! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Tanaike. I have one issue from your suggested code. It replaces the value of the other columns with null like the Payment Method, LA Customer, Cleaners, etc.

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added one more modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?